# XSLT 2.0 split an element around a specified child

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I need to determine a way to split an element around a specified child element when it's encountered. Example input:

```
<root>
...
<span>Here's that <link>link</link> for you.</span>
...
</root>
```

Desired output:

```
<root>
...
<span>Here's that </span><link>link</link><span> for you.</span>
...
</root>
```

I know I could use tokenize to split a string around given text, but i need to split an element around a given element, and I'm not sure what the best way is to tackle this.

Note that I'm working with a highly constrained DTD, so the most complex nesting case(s) we might see would look something like this:

Example input:

```
<root>
...
<span>Here's that <link>link</link> and this <link>link</link>and this <link>link</link>for you.</span>
...
</root>
```

Desired output:

```
<root>
...
<span>Here's that </span><link>link</link><span> and this </span><link>link</link><span> and this </span><link>link</link><span> for you.</span>
...
</root>
```

Comment: I think you need to give more than one example to explain what you want to do. What would happen with `<span>Here's <span>that <link>link</link> for</span> you.</span>` for instance? And in general do explain which version of XSLT you use.

Comment: I think I added 2.0 to the title as you were adding this comment.  I'm working from an extremely constrained DTD.  <span> in this instance can contain text or <link> (which can only contain text). So, as far as nesting is concerned, the only more complexity we could see is multiple instances of <link> embedded in one <span>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XSLT 2 or 3 it seems like a grouping problem, solved with (assuming you only want to apply that solution to `span` elements having at least a `link` child):

```
  <xsl:template match="span[link]">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-adjacent="boolean(self::link)">
          <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                  <span>
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                  </span>
              </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>
```

pluse the identity transformation template of course to copy/handle the rest. XSLT 3 online example at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qVRKwK/1, XSLT 2 http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/gWmuiHN.

Comment: Thanks! I knew it had to be a grouping problem. I'd tried virtually the same approach, but using group-adjacent="self::link"> (per the wc3 group-adjacent example), however, that approach resulted in blank output.  I'm not sure I understand why this works and their approach doesn't in my case.

Comment: Next time consider to add your attempt if you want an explanation, I am not sure which example exactly you refer to, the XSLT 3 spec in https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#grouping-examples has an example doing `group-adjacent="self::ul or self::ol"` so there (due to the `or`) you directly have a boolean value as the grouping key, in my example for your case a `group-adjacent="boolean(self::link)"` works as it ensures the code checks for adjacent `link` elements but gives us a boolean value to check for inside the `xsl:for-each-group`.

Comment: Thinking about your attempt with `group-adjacent="self::link"` I think it should result in error "[ERR XTTE1100] It is a type error if the grouping key evaluated using the group-adjacent attribute is an empty sequence"